# Ubuntu 12.04 screen Orientation issue

Tags: screen

Installed 12.04 LTS in my pc and there is no problem for display. But when I connect my PC to my LCD tv (sony bravia bx 300), its not detecting the screen orientation, ie it only detects 1280*7xx (4:3 orientation) so that it seems stretched, but my tv has 16:9 orientation screen.

note: When I was using 10.04 LTS there was no problem.

Comment: Did you try to change `Resolution` from `System Settings -> Display` there would be some more options there.. Reply what happens..

Comment: @SauravKumar tried to change display resolution but it showing only 1280*7xx (4:3),800*600 but  i need  1280*7xx (16:9).